# How do I make a NX Library(aka. Module)?

Tags: angular, lib

When making a new view how do I use NX to scaffold the new library?

I tried using the recommended CLI code from the NX READ_ME documentation. Code scaffolding
Run ng g component my-component --project=my-app to generate a new component. However, I'm not sure this is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

For example to create a logger library in the libs/shared folder:

```
nx g @nrwl/angular:library logger --directory=shared
```

You'll find list of default generators at the end of the `nx.json` file.

Or search the docs e.g. type "Angular" into search https://nx.dev/getting-started/intro

List of generators: https://nx.dev/packages/angular#generators